# Access dynamically-named form from an angular controller

Tags: angularjs, django-angular

All,

I have a form inside an Angular controller.  But the name of that form is dynamically-generated (by Django) from the server.  Does anybody know how I can access that form (w/ the intention of changing the validity of certain items after some interaction w/ the server).

Here is some code:

**my_template.html:**

```
<html>
  <div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController as my_controller">
      <form name={{ form.form_name }}
        {% for field in form %}
          {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
      </form>
      <button ng-click="do_something">do something</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

**my_view.py:**

```
def my_view(request):
  form = MyForm(form_name=generate_a_random_string())
  return render_to_template({"form":form}
  return render_to_response('my_template.html', {"form": form})
```

**my_app.js:**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("MyApp");
    app.controller("MyController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.do_something = function() {
        /* OBVIOUSLY THIS DOESN'T WORK */
        /* BUT WHAT DO I REPLACE "my_form" WITH ? */
        my_form['some_field_name'].$setValidity('some_validity_type', false);
        my_form['some_field_name'].$setDirty();
      }
    }]);
});
```

If it helps, I am using django-angular to make my Django forms play nicely w/ Angular.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure whether I got your question right, you should be able to get the form from `$scope.form.form_name` right?

Comment: Nope.  If I try that I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'form_name' of undefined`.  I think I need to actually specify the name of the form.

Comment: Try removing the {{}} for form name. Just have it as form.form_name and then try getting it as I mentioned earlier

Answer (score 0):

The name of the form as in

```
<form name="myForm">
```

will be reflected in your controller as a NgFormController of the same name

```
myController.myForm
```

I think part of the problem is that you have `{{ form.form_name }}` in your template which from what I can tell hasn't been initialized in your controller. 
You probably need to initialize your form names inside your controller first, then use an ng-repeat to build your form DOM elements and pull the name from there.  Then you can access the NgFormController by using `this.form_name` inside your view controller.

Comment: The double-brackets are from Django.  In "my_view.py" I pass a Django Form with a form_name property to the "my_template.html" template.  It is unfortunate that Django and Angular use the same syntax for variables.  Just assume it is a value that has not been computed by Angular.

Comment: so once angular links the template to the controller, what does the name attribute look like?  I assume `name="someName"` right?

Comment: Yes. `<form name="my_big_complex_name">`.

Comment: is there any common prefix/suffix?  The only way I can think to get this without having a data construct is to get the keys off your controller and see if they fit a particular pattern, say MyCustom**Form** so that you know that key is unique to the django-created forms.  Then you can access them through some loop.  The other way is loop through all your keys and see if `this.myCustomForm instanceof NgFormController` or something of that nature

Comment: Aha!  I just figured it out (mostly).  I can pass the name of the form to the controller function `do_something`.